# How do I reference external jar files in a common directory (not libs) to build android project using ant?

Tags: android, ant, build, jar, libs

I would like to build several android projects that reference the same jar files using ant. I do not want to copy the jar file to each libs directory in the project (due to how the source control tree is set up). The [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611105/how-to-specify-lib-folder-for-jars-when-using-android-generated-ant-build-file) I [find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465285/how-to-build-an-android-app-with-external-libraries-using-ant) here say "put them in the libs directory" which does not solve this problem.

So the question is, how do I configure my android ant build scripts to reference a common jar in a separate directory outside the project (not in "libs")?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the sdk, there are ant files under `tools/ant`.  In `main_rules.xml`, you can find the following code section:

```
<!-- Directory for the third party java libraries -->
<property name="jar.libs.dir" value="libs" />
<property name="jar.libs.absolute.dir" location="${jar.libs.dir}" />
<!-- create a path with all the jar files, from the main project and the
     libraries -->
<path id="jar.libs.ref">
    <fileset dir="${jar.libs.absolute.dir}" includes="*.jar" />
    <path refid="project.libraries.jars" />
</path>
```

This is how the ant build code determines where to get the jars from.  You could overload the value of `jar.libs.dir` in your build.properties since that is read before this section and would overload the value. Pointing that at a common directory you intend to use will do what you are suggesting. You may need to play with it some to get it to work the way you want.

One caveat is that I'm not sure if this will negatively impact other build life cycle activities.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like the newer sdk tools make this easier to accomplish.  I have a master libs folder  that all my android projects share and I just added this to the `ant.properties` file to make it look up one level for those libs.

```
jar.libs.dir=../libs
```

Comment: Pointing to util project shared by all other projects also confirmed working, ex:
jar.libs.dir=../MyUtilAnd3rdPartyLibraryProject/libs

Comment: Weird.. it isn't working for me.. I tried echoing the `jar.libs.dir` value just before the compile target and it show `../libs` but compile still fails. This is on SDK Tools 21.0.1.

Comment: Found the issue and am posting an answer

Answer (score 3):

As per the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251438/android-sdk-tools-r20-javadocs-for-3rd-party-libraries-and-ant-builds/14080205#14080205) and my answer taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12468873/780694), the offered solution does not work as of now. Until the filed bug is fixed. The solution, as mentioned in the referenced answer, is copied below.

---

I add this to my `custom_rules.xml` template and it seems to be working fine.
I supposed it's only a few more lines than adding path to the `ant.properties` file until we get a better solution.

```
<target name="-pre-compile">
    <path id="project.all.jars.path">
    <path path="${toString:project.all.jars.path}"/>
    <fileset dir="${jar.libs.dir}">
        <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
    </path>
</target>
```

Answer (score -2):

If you use Linux, just make symbolic links of the external jar files, then place them all in `libs`. Ant will work fine.

**Edited**

Make sure place all symbolic links directly in `libs` (not sub directories). I'm sure this can be re-config by ant script. But I'm not familiar with ant :-)