# Is jar.libs.dir not being overridden properly?

Tags: java, android, xml, ant

After [referencing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935753/android-include-external-jar-in-build-without-eclipse) just a [few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217643/how-to-add-external-jar-libraries-to-an-android-project-from-the-command-line) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312478/how-do-i-reference-external-jar-files-in-a-common-directory-not-libs-to-build) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7185488/android-what-is-the-folder-name-of-the-jar-files-lib-or-libs), I found that none of those answers are working in my project. Dropping jars into the /libs folder of each individual module, the ant build runs correctly and produces output. After deleting all of the /libs folders and including an `ant.properties` file ( a.k.a. `build.properties` ) in every module I need, the ant build has stopped working.

ant.properties:

```
# This file is used to override default values used by the Ant build system.
#
# This file must be checked in Version Control Systems, as it is
# integral to the build system of your project.

# This file is only used by the Ant script.

# You can use this to override default values such as
#  'source.dir' for the location of your java source folder and
#  'out.dir' for the location of your output folder.

jar.libs.dir=../ExternalJars/libs
```

Build.xml

```
<property file="ant.properties" />

<loadproperties srcFile="project.properties" />

<!-- version-tag: 1 -->
 <import file="${sdk.dir}/tools/ant/build.xml" />

<target name="full-debug" depends="debug">
</target>

<target name="full-release" depends="clean,release">
</target>
```

As far as I can tell, the files are properly written - the pathing is all correct relative to the ant.properties file, jars are where they should be, modules use all of the correct classes and parts, etc.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is a known bug: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33194

Comment: Not the answer I was looking for, but the right answer all the same. Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 8):

Based on the other answer, this is what I implemented to the build.xml script, to support the jar.libs.dir property:

```
<target name="-pre-compile">
    <property name="project.all.jars.path.temp" value="${toString:project.all.jars.path}" />
    <path id="project.all.jars.path">
        <path path="${project.all.jars.path.temp}"/>
        <fileset dir="${jar.libs.dir}">
            <include name="*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>
</target>
```

Since the **<path path="..."/>** is used, it looks safe enough, even if more than one JAR file is added by default to the path element.

Comment: In my experience, this would discard the existing project.all.jars.path content (tried Ant 1.8.4, 1.9.0 and 1.9.2, got the same result). Adding a <property name="project.all.jars.path.temp" value="${toString:project.all.jars.path}" /> just below the opening target tag and referencing it like <path path="${project.all.jars.path.temp}" /> inside the path override seems to fix the issue.